# How to retrieve value from series created in pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

This is about using python and pandas to read excel file, I have not been able to find a working example.

My file's name is something like:

```
2018 Historical Banking Record For Branch 12345.xlsx
```

The Excel has content like below (sorry I don't know how to attach the file to this post):

```
 2  CD ABC PRODUCT                                                                  
    MA  RI  NH  CT  VT  CA  CR  DE  PHI NJ  ON  FL  WA  DX  HW  AK  MI  IL
01/01/18    1.01    1.61    1.80    1.46    1.69    1.73    1.64    1.64    1.74    1.71    1.68    1.74    1.68    1.87    1.77    2.04    2.05    1.76
01/08/18    2.01    2.61    2.80    2.46    2.69    2.73    2.64    2.64    2.74    2.71    2.68    1.73    1.67    1.84    1.74    2.06    2.04    1.76
01/15/18    3.01    3.61    3.80    3.46    3.69    3.73    3.64    3.64    3.74    3.71    3.68    1.74    1.68    1.86    1.75    2.06    2.04    1.76
01/22/18    4.01    4.61    4.80    4.46    4.69    4.73    4.64    4.64    4.74    4.71    4.68    1.76    1.74    1.73    1.66    1.93    1.84    1.87
01/29/18    5.01    5.61    5.80    5.46    2.01    5.73    1.82    5.64    5.74    5.71    5.68    1.74    1.72    1.71    1.62    1.91    1.82    1.85
```

[image]

My code is something like below:

```
import pandas as pd
xl = pd.ExcelFile("../data/sample.xlsx", engine='xlrd')
```

I am able to get the first row cells's value with

```
xl.book._sharedstrings[0] ~ xl.book._sharedstrings[18]
```

What I need to do is how to loop all the rows and get all the cell's value?

Eventually I need to generate a new dataframe with the structure like below:

```
product p_date region p_value c_date eom
CD ABC PRODUCT 01/01/18 MA 1.01 18/10/24 18/10/31
```

All the fields are explained as below:

1. product: for this sheet, it is always the same: CD ABC PRODUCT
2. p_date: should be from the first column:

   ```
   01/01/18
   01/08/18
   01/15/18
   01/22/18
   01/29/18
   ```
3. region:

   ```
   MA
   RI
   NH
   CT
   ....
   ```
4. p_value: the decimal under each region, e.g. 1.01
5. c_date: today's date, 18/10/24
6. eom: the last date for this month, 18/10/31

there are 18 regions in this sheet, meaning 18 records will be created for the new dataframe.

I am able to get all the cells except for the first column for p_date:

```
01/01/18
01/08/18
01/15/18
01/22/18
01/29/18
```

It seems to be from a "Series" as shown below, but I don't know how to retrieve value from it.

[image]

I can use list(df["MA"]) to convert Series df["MA"] to a list, but I still cannot get the p_date.

Ideally I need to loop each row when generate/append the dataframe

```
cur_row=[wampproduct, wamp_date, wampregion, rsp, wamp, date_pull, eom]
df_row = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, data=cur_row)
df = df.append(df_row, ignore_index=True)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Just curious: Does `xl = pd.read_excel("../data/sample.xlsx")` solve your problem? It should return the whole pandas DataFrame. Note that if there are more than one sheet, you'll have to provide the sheet_name. Refer to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: Thanks, sorry I tested that out already and it didn't resolve the need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of operation is called a melt. It is essentially the inverse of pivoting a dataframe. Also, as Mathew pointed out in a comment, using the read_excel is a bit simpler since it directly returns a dataframe. The following code block runs the melt.

```
fname = ../data/sample.xlsx''
date_pull = pd.to_datetime('2018-10-18')
eom =  pd.to_datetime('2018-10-31')

# get product name out of excel file
product = pd.read_excel(fname, nrows=1, header=None, usecols=[1])
product = product.loc[0, 0]
product

# load data from excel fail
df = pd.read_excel(fname, header=1)

# rename index to p_date and make a column
df.index.rename('p_date', inplace=True)
df = df.reset_index()

# add product to df
df['product'] = product

# melt 
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['product', 'p_date'], var_name='region', value_name='p_value')

# add c_date and eom to data frame
df['c_date'] = date_pull
df['eom'] = eom
```

Comment: Thank you very much, how can I get the sheet's name?

Comment: I am also looking for an auto number id as the identity to be assigned to the df, can you tell me how to do it? Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Maybe pack the dataframes in a dictionary and use the excel filename + sheetname as the keyval?

Comment: Thank you, indeed I am able to get the sheet name, more wondering on how to retrieve the excel cell row by row and generate data row and append it to the new dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

With @alexdor's code plus my own code I am now able to generate the needed result like below:

```
,product,p_date,region,p_value,c_date,eom
0,CD Short-Term WAMP,2010-01-01,MA,0.8763918845487475,201812,2018-12-31
1,CD Short-Term WAMP,2010-01-08,MA,0.8600652449166932,201812,2018-12-31
2,CD Short-Term WAMP,2010-01-15,MA,0.8593079486202981,201812,2018-12-31
```

To remove the sequence number which will cause issue later, set the index=False as below:

```
df_csv.to_csv(physical_file, index=False)
```